# React Private Route and hooks context and reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I try to implement Auth with private route and Hooks with useReducer and Context. When i try ti route at dashboard i get an error

```
Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
```

Why? my code on stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-caertn

can you help me?
Thank you so much.
Marco.Italy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were mixing Provider/Consumer and Hook components.  Here's an updated example which introduced a `useAuth` hook.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fqsfpn